# How to validate Token from personal Microsoft Account?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I created a API that I try to protect with AAD.
It's already working for Accounts from my organization and Accounts from other organizations but not for personal Microsoft Accounts.

I already tryed different Endpoints but I think the common Endpoint should be the correct Endpoint if I want any Account to be able to sign in.

This is how my API Startup looks:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(o =>
            {
               o.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddJwtBearer(o =>
            {
                o.Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common";
                o.TokenValidationParameters = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    // Both App ID URI and client id are valid audiences in the access token
                    ValidAudiences = new List<string>
                    {
                        "APP ID",
                    },
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
               };
            });
```

And this is how I get the accesstoken at javascript:

```
    var applicationConfig = { //Cloudlist API via TestApp
        clientID: "APP ID",        
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common",
        graphScopes: ["https://hsde.onmicrosoft.com/APP ID/User"]
    };
    var myMSALObj = new Msal.UserAgentApplication(applicationConfig.clientID, 
    applicationConfig.authority, null, { storeAuthStateInCookie: true, 
    cacheLocation: "localStorage" });

        myMSALObj.loginPopup(applicationConfig.graphScopes).then(function (idToken) { 
            myMSALObj.acquireTokenSilent(applicationConfig.graphScopes).then(function (accessToken) {
                callAPI(accessToken);;
            });
        }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
        });
```

When I sign in with a personal Microsoft Account and use the accessToken to call the API I get a 401 Unauthorized Error.
The response header says: 
www-authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature key was not found"

Is there anything I have to do differently when signing in with a personal Microsoft Account ?

Comment: Have you tried using a tool like http://calebb.net/ to inspect your token? Some values might not be set properly. If you know what you are expecting to see in there this might help you.

Comment: I used jwt.io to inspect the token, I couldn't find anything that would make the token invalid. The aud is the same as for accounts from a organization. The kid is different but I'm not sure if that is causing the validation to fail.

Answer (score 0):

First, get a token and try to decoded in jwt.io just to check if audience id is the same that you are using in you web api.

Comment: Thanks, I should have mentioned that I already tryed this and that it is the same.